# Update controller after the job is done

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a controller action, which triggers a delayed job, which has `after_perform` hook in which another delayed job is triggered.

I need to render a view, after  all jobs are done and show a spinner to a user, while the jobs are still running.

The jobs look like this:

```
class DuplicateShipmentJob < ApplicationJob
  after_perform do |job|
    shipment = job.arguments.first[:shipment]
    shipment_ids = Shipment.where(public_id: shipment.public_id).map(&:id)
    bulk_shipment_process = BulkShipmentProcess.new
    bulk_shipment_process.shipment_ids = shipment_ids
    bulk_shipment_process.user = shipment.user

    if bulk_shipment_process.save
      Shipment.where(public_id: shipment.public_id).each do |shipment|
        shipment.bulk_shipment_process_id = bulk_shipment_process.id
      end
      BulkShipmentsProcessor.delay.process_bulk_shipments(args)
    end
   end

 def perform(shipment:, label_count:)
   label_count.times do
     duplicated_shipment = shipment.dup
     duplicated_shipment.package = shipment.package.dup
     duplicated_shipment.save!
   end
  end
 end
```

What is the best way to do it?

I am hesitating between ajax requests to the DB and setting an action cable to listen to job result.

Controller looks like this:

```
class ShipmentsController < ApplicationController
 def replicate_shipment
  @shipment = build_shipment
  @shipment.save!
  DuplicateShipmentJob.perform_later(
    shipment: @shipment,
    label_count: @shipment.create_multiple_shipments.to_i - 1,
  )
  # here i need to wait until the process instance appears in the DB
  @bulk_shipment_process = BulkShipmentProcess.where(id: Shipment.last.bulk_shipment_process_id) 
  redirect_to bulk_shipment_process_path(@bulk_shipment_process)
 end
end
```

Comment: You may use DuplicateShipmentJob.new.perform() rather than perform it later.

Comment: @fidato, i use `perform later`, because i want it to run asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

I'd first recommend storing jobs in the database and looping over the related job that is related to the user who triggered it and identifiy it.

Once you submit the job, trigger the spinner, after this, try to hardcode an open loop that retrieve the related job from the database, and check that the status of it is `done`:

```
        loop do
          status = DelayedJob.find(JOB_ID)
          case status
          when 'DONE' then return true
          when 'PROCESSING' then sleep(10)
          else raise(JobRunFailed, "Job run failed with: #{status}")
          end
        end
```

, take down the spinner and output the relavant message you want.

Of course the open loop logic could be hardcoded in the frontend side of your application if you want too.

So to recap the steps:

1. Identifiy the relavent job in the database after it is being stored
2. trigger the wait spinner  *Here where you redirect to bulk_shipment_process_path*
3. Loop over the identified job till it is marked as `done` or `performed`
4. change the corresponding interface after the loop is being broken out.

step 3 and 4 could be really only frontend related steps and would have nothing to do with the `ShipmentsController` anymore.

Comment: Good idea. I use `Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job`. HOw can I retrieve status from it?

Comment: That is something you have to dig into on your own. Maybe this is a good start:
https://medium.com/galvanize/insights-into-our-delayed-job-queue-part-1-b53879ec91f7

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with following solution.

I moved instantiating of `BulkShipmentProcess` to the controller and after saving it, redirected to `show` action for this instance and triggered the first job, passing the instance as a job argument.

Inside the job the second job was triggered and some propertied assigned to the `BulkShipmentProcess` instance.

While on the `bulk_shipment_process/id` page the JS was polling the DB for the instance to get new properties assigned and upon success rendered these properties.

Controller:

```
class ShipmentsController < ApplicationController
  def replicate_shipment
    @shipment = build_shipment
    @shipment.save!
    @bulk_shipment_process = BulkShipmentProcess.new()
    @bulk_shipment_process.save
    if @bulk_shipment_process.id?
       DuplicateShipmentJob.perform_later(@bulk_shipment_process)
       redirect_to bulk_shipment_process_path(@bulk_shipment_process)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "error"
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Job:

```
class DuplicateShipmentJob < ApplicationJob
 def perform(bulk_shipment_process:)
  # do something
  # assign new attributes to the instance of interest
  # trigger second delayed job upon instance of interest
 end
end
```

Polling function:

```
currentStatus = (element) ->
  element.find("div").data("status")

statusFinished = (status) ->
  status.startsWith("finish") ||
    status.startsWith("fail") ||
    status.startsWith("unknown") ||
    status.startsWith("stuck")

statusUpdate = (element, done_action) ->
  $.ajax
    url: element.data("target")
    success: (data) ->
      element.html data
      status = currentStatus element

      if statusFinished(status)
        console.log "done_action " + done_action
        if done_action == "reload"
          console.log "reload"
          location.reload()
      else
        setTimeout (->
          statusUpdate(element, done_action)
          return
        ), 5000
      return
  return

$ ->
  $('[data-controller="status-update"]').each (index) ->
    target = $(this).data("target")
    status = currentStatus $(this)
    done_action = $(this).data("done")

    unless statusFinished(status)
      statusUpdate($(this), done_action)
    return
```